# Why do I get different posted file content type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm working with FileUpload in asp.net, I get to make it work, several times, but for some reason when I transfer my files(solution) on other computer this is my condition where I'm checking the type of File that is being uploaded:

```
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

Everything is working, I successfully saved the values of "excel" file to SQL Database. And when I transfer my files it suddenly doesn't work, since the `FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType` returns **application/octet-stream**.

Big question here is, why does this happen? On my other computer it returns the content type just fine, but on the other computer it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have a file association defined on both machines?  That would happen when Excel is installed.

Comment: what do you mean file association defined?

Comment: I'm talking Windows here... when you install an app such as Excel, it also installs conceptual connections between the app and specific file extensions. If you don't have Excel, then I don't think you have that connection, ergo your logic fails because that computer doesn't know what an Excel file is and instead calls it an application/octet-stream. I think application/octet-stream is the default file type when nothing else fits. See https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream.

Comment: oh.. probably you're right.. but i'm wondering about is that I tested in 3 computers, 2 with excel installed, 1 without,.. on 2pc with excel, 1working, 1 isnot.. and the one without excel it's really returning application/octet-stream... BTW, thanks a lot for this idea.. damn i didn't knew about this

Comment: Research file associations and I'm sure you can programmatically create the ones you need without having to install Excel. That will give you control over your operating environment.

Comment: problem now is that, without the access db Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable uploading the excel is making an issue.. is there a way for me to resolve this when deploying my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can resolve when deploying your application. The program that creates the file association should be executed during deployment. You'll have to write that program or find it online.

Comment: but what if it's web.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'what if it's web.' The file association has to be created on the server-side, I think, based on your problem description. That means you will add a small program to your distribution package: that small program will run on the server-side before your ASP.Net app is installed there. I guess you could also put the file association creation code in the app itself and have it run out of the Application_Start event in global.asax

Comment: oh so you mean i'll just include the executable file into the server? sorry I'm new to deployment

Comment: I think that's what yo need to do. Look at global.asax.

Comment: so here's the thing, i uploaded my files in hostbuddy. and mapped to the path of the webforms.. but when i visit the url provided by hostbuddy, i get an iis error http://ghostman-001-site1.1tempurl.com/